# generating serial numbers in mysql with auto increment

Tags: mysql

I had tried to generate a serial number whether the activity is rescheduled(the number of time it has been rescheduled) but getting wrong output.

In the following image 1st 5 rows are correct, but when it comes for new activity, then it should again starts from "Reschedule 1 ".
query here..

```
SELECT  concat('Reschedule ',@a:=@a+1) Reschedule_type, 
        activity, old_date,new_date
FROM    application_calender_reschedule_view
    , (SELECT @a:= 0) as a;
```

How do i do this...?

**Please find following snapshot for reference.**   
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynpwt.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the previous activity in a variable and sort by the activities so all are guaranteed to be together:

```
SELECT  concat('Reschedule ', if(@activity = activity, @a:=@a+1, @a := 1)
              ) as Reschedule_type, 
        activity, old_date, new_date,
        @activity := activity
FROM    application_calender_reschedule_view cross join
        (SELECT @a:= 0, @activity := '') as a
ORDER BY activity, old_date
```

Comment: Thank u ..i got the result.. error found because of join... i rearranged it.. anyway thank u